# Adaptec raid 1 on ibm 206m

Tags: windows-server-2003, raid, adaptec

So I have an IBM xseries 206m. It was working fine and one day after a reboot I noticed something weird about the RAID.

It has a RAID 1 configuration, after this reboot (windows updates), I saw two windows drives appear in My computer. I rebooted many times but no change.

I went into the raid setup and it said the raid is degraded, even if all members were present. So I formatted the second drive, took it out and plugged it back in. The raid started to rebuild and completed successfully. I then booted into the OS, but the same thing happened, the two hard drives showed up in My computer. I can also see Raid is not active because when files are written only the first hard drive's light blink.

I installed the Adaptec storage manager and when I open it I see all my drives but no logical drives. If I boot into the card management I see all the drives + the logical drive.

I really don't know what is going on...

The controller is AIC-9405, on Windows server 2003 STD x32

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try downloading "support archive" from adaptec utility and sending it to vendors support - most likely something is wrong with your controller.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fake-RAID controller, it needs a special driver to work in RAID mode. As Windows may have both drivers installed, they are easy to mix up. Try finding HostRAID driver from Adaptec or IBM site. Or break the mirror up and use Windows mirroring instead.